# Regex matching a word excluding some others

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I try to create a regex who capture a word in a line, (basically it's a disk device name) but excluding all names with some format. For example:

```
if (/^\s*(?:\d+\s+){3}(\S+)\s.*/)
```

This regex is matching:

```
8       80 7814026584 sdf
```

sdf in this line. But there are some ram disks I want to exclude. eg ram1, ram2, ram3, ..ram15 etc. How I can exclude all device starting by "ram"?

Comment: Like [`/^\s*(?:\d+\s+){3}((?!ram\d+\s)\S+)\s.*/`](https://regex101.com/r/cndjLc/1) perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the example you show it's easier to [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the line, and then you can also process easily.

I take it that the fourth field is always the criterion for whether to process or exclude the line.

Assuming that `$fh` is the filehandle for the file you are processing

```
while (<$fh>) 
{
    my @fields = split;

    # Skip this line if the fourth field starts with 'ram'
    next if $fields[3] =~ /^ram/;

    # Process as needed
    # Numbers are at indices 0, 1, 2, and disk device name is $fields[3]
}
```

The `split` above is the same as `split ' ', $_`, where `' '` is any amount of any white space.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But regex you provided is hardcoded for field 3 right? What if the line to be captured is something like:

3    64   78150744 sdf 157 735 2168 1720 1745 437 17432 440 0 1960 2160 

Do you think it will still capture sdf and exclude all ram?

Comment: @JavaRed  The example you provided is hard-coded with three numbers, separated by spaces.  Then the pattern to accept (`sdf`) or to exclude (`ram`) comes.  If that's not always the case then it would be even better to split and manipulate an array, than to fiddle with a regex of growing complexity.  If the `sdf` in your comment above is `ram`, yes the code in my answer will skip that line.  It's the fourth field on which it's checking.

Comment: @JavaRed  Are you saying that you can have `ram` anywhere on the line, and that you still have to skip the line?  (That's in fact much easier.)  The `split` in my answer splits the line by spaces, returning all fields into an array.  In your example from the comment above, it will have the first three numbers, then `sdf` in the fourth field, then 11 more fields with numbers.  Arrays start at `0` index.  So we check the fourth field (`$fields[3]`) and if it's `/^ram/` we move onto the next line.  If not, we process.  Is this not what you need?

Comment: yes I try to modify a long code and as I understood disk name could be anywhere in the line. So regex should capture any character containing disk format eg  sda1 sd3 hd1 hd4 sdd12 etc but it should exclude all device name starting by ram regardless the field.

Comment: @JavaRed Ah.  Then, if you have on line `sda1 ... hd1 ... ram1 ... sdd12` -- do you skip the whole line or do you just exclude the `ram` field (and keep and process others)?

Comment: For example:

1) 3    64   78150744 hdb 157 735 2168 1720 1745 437 17432 440 0 1960 2160  (capture hdb)

2) 223 6675576 sdh 546456  (capture sdh)
3) 8233 33333333 sde23  (capture sde23)
4) 34343 343 12121 ram1 (skip ram1)
5)  45454 ram2 3434343 445 (skip ram2)
6) 1 6 16384 ram6 (skip ram6)

Comment: @JavaRed  So each example is one line, and each line contains **only one** `hdb` or `sdh` or `ram` ... is that correct? In your example 2), 3), and 5), the disk is _not the fourth_ thing on the line.  This disagrees with your regex in the question.  If the disk is always the fourth field on the line, and there can only be one disk label per line, the code in the answer does what you want.  Try it, test it.

Comment: @JavaRed  I updated the answer with a few comments, meant to clarify what the code does.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like working after a couple of trials.

Comment: @JavaRed  Great, glad to hear that :)  Let me know if more explanations or additions would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want special execute ram than i think this short regex helps?

**[^r]+ram\w{1,2}**

[image]

Comment: Should I add this at the end of my regex?

if (/^\s*(?:\d+\s+){3}(\S+)\s.*/)